# Why don't show images when go to edit form in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, edit

In my sample ruby on rails app, there is a model name Student. This is it's schema file.

```
create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.integer  "age"
t.string   "image"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

I'm using postgreSQL DB. And my
*...app\views\students_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(student) do |f| %>
<% if student.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(student.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this student from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
  <% student.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :age %>
<%= f.number_field :age %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :image %><br>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>

</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

then,
My create, index & show work properly but when I go to edit form it doesn't show image name in choose file button. It seems empty. 
I'm using carrierwave gem to upload images. What should I do to get image file name into edit page? Thank you.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want the name of the image to appear in the image upload field?

Comment: Please post your StudentsController.rb and Student.rb (Model file).

Comment: Image name is not shown in choose file button. You will need some html/css/js magic if you want that to happen. Why do you need this behavior?

Comment: @Ozgar, yes, I want the name of image appear in 'choose file' button.

Iceman, I need to know which file had been uploaded in DB. Why can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons you can not autopopulate file_fields. Imagine going to a site that automatically adds "C:/any/file/on/your.system" to a form and submits it. Not a good idea!

So what you can do is add a custom label to the form displaying the name of the existing image if it exists.

For prettyness you could also add a script (js or jQuery) that hides the original label and shows the custom if an image is already present.

I don't have access to my rails environment right now, but if you're still struggling when I get home from work I will edit this answer with an example.

EDIT:

Okay, your question reminded me that I had the same flaw in my project. I am using [bootstrap forms](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms) to make my forms look better without much effort. The vanilla gem does however not fix the kind of [ugly file upload fields](http://www.phpgang.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/PHPGang_File_Upload.jpg) so I decided to use [bootstrap filestyle](https://github.com/mauriciopasquier/bootstrap-filestyle-rails) to make them blend in better.

Neither of these gems takes care of the placeholder though. So I added some jQuery to fix that.

If you want this in your project, add both of the gems and make the following changes to your code.

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(student, layout: :horizontal) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.number_field :age %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, data: { placeholder: student.avatar_identifier || "No file selected" } %>
    <%= f.form_group do %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then in the [bootstrap initializer](https://github.com/mauriciopasquier/bootstrap-filestyle-rails#usage) file_input.js:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  $(":file").filestyle({
    buttonText: " Bläddra",
    buttonBefore: true
  });

  $(":file").each(function() {
    ph = $(this).data("placeholder");
    $(this).filestyle('placeholder', ph);
  });
});
```

I hope this will help you!

P.S. I also removed the part you had with errors because I assumed that this is only used for validation errors on create/update. These types of errors are handled beautifully with bootstrap forms and are not required to be added manually.

Answer (score -2):

First of all u must create uploader

```
rails generate uploader Image
```

add uploader to you Student model

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

U can test you code in `rails console`

```
s = Student.new
s.remote_image_url = "http://itc.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Depositphotos_2337426_original.jpg"
s.save
```

If succsesfull u get msg from SQL

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.